Variable not decrementing correctly
I am trying to write a script for Unity that will allow my character to jump. The way I have it set up is that there is a variable that stores the amount of jumps the character has left. When the jump button is pressed, if that variable is greater than zero, the code applies a vertical force to the character, and is then supposed to decrement the variable by one. At the end of the tick, if the character is touching the ground, the amount of jumps will be reset to the original amount of jumps, which in this case is 1. However, for some reason the variable storing the number of jumps does not properly decrease. For some reason, the first time the character jumps after touching the ground, the variable does not decrement properly, and remains at 1. However, during the same jump, if before touching the ground the jump key is pressed again, the character will jump mid-air, but this time everything behaves properly, and the jump counter remains at zero until the character touches the ground again. This only happens when the number of jumps is set to one. When set to two or higher, everything behaves fine.
Here's my code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BodyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb; 
    public float jumpHeight = 10;
    public int jumpNum = 1;
    public float speed = 10;
    int jumpCount = 1;
    bool updateRunning = false;
bool touchingGround = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        if(updateRunning==false){
            updateRunning = true;
            touchingGround = Physics.Raycast(transform.position,Vector3.down,1);
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
                // Debug.Log("zPressed");
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed,rb.velocity.y,0);
                
            }else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speed,rb.velocity.y,0);   
                
            }else if(touchingGround){
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,rb.velocity.y,0);
            }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && jumpCount > 0){
                
                touchingGround=false;   
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0,jumpHeight,0),ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                // touchingGround = Physics.Raycast(transform.position,Vector3.down,1);
                jumpCount = jumpCount - 1;
                Debug.Log(jumpCount);
            }

            if(touchingGround){
                jumpCount = jumpNum;
                // Debug.Log("touching ground");
                
            }
            Debug.Log($"Jumpcount:{jumpCount} TouchingGround:{touchingGround}" );
            updateRunning = false;
        }
    }


}







So what if the raycast still hits something in the next frame .. before your character jumped high enough? And what exactly is the purpose of updateRunning ..?

@derHugo That can't be it, because as I said, it works fine when the number of jumps the character has is greater than 1. Also, I set the raycast length to be exactly the length from the start of the raycast to the bottom of the character's hitbox, so that wouldn't happen. The purpose of updateRunning is to make sure that there weren't two instances of the code running at once. I know that probably doesn't happen, but I just wanted to make sure.

Try putting this code in FixedUpdate(), instead of Update(). Unity's physics system runs at a fixed timestep (60hz by default), while Update() runs once a frame. So it's possible that you jump and then your code immediately detects that the player is still on the ground (because the physics system hasn't ran since your last velocity change)

@ipodtouch0218 then you would need a combination of both though because you shouldn't get single event user input (GetKeyDown) in FixedUpdate because you might miss one (btw FixedUpdate runs with 50Hz by default ;) )

@derHugo true, I just saw the GetKey and didn't notice that they switched to GetKeyDown for the jump functionality.
